# If bash doesn't preserve a backslash in double quotes, then why does echo -e "\n" work?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

#### From bash manpage

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of  all  characters  within the quotes,  with  the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.

With this in mind, how is it that `echo -ne "\n"` produces a newline? Wouldn't the shell expand "\n" before it ever gets passed to `echo`?

I thought it might work because `echo` is a builtin and so the shell is smart enough to do the right thing.  However, even calling the external `/usr/bin/echo -ne "\n"` works.

What's even more curious is that regardless if I double-quote or single-quote `\n`, the following two commands show that bash is passing `\\n` as the argument:

```
$ strace /usr/bin/echo "\n" 2>&1 | head -n1
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["/usr/bin/echo", "\\n"], [/* 33 vars */]) = 0
$ strace /usr/bin/echo '\n' 2>&1 | head -n1
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["/usr/bin/echo", "\\n"], [/* 33 vars */]) = 0
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read on:

> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following  characters: `$`, `` ` ``,  `"`, `\`, or `<newline>`.

Since it’s just followed by a letter, it does not retain its special meaning and is passed literally to the program.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what's going on.